# INNER JOIN and multi-row data in SQL, wp_postmeta table

Tags: sql, wordpress, post-meta

I am trying to make a report with different data from my WordPress tables. I would like to know which referencing has made how many views and display the phone number there. I already have all the data in my table, but I'm not doing it right for my query.

Here are my (summary) tables and contents.

Table wp_posts

| id | post_title |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | First Post |
| 200 | Second Post |

Table wp_postmeta

| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | postviews_total | 3493 |
| 2 | 100 | listing_tel | 04444444 |
| 3 | 200 | postviews_total | 2525 |
| 4 | 200 | listing_tel | 0555555 |

Desired outcome

| Listing Title | Field | Value | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First Post | postviews_total | 3493 | 04444444 |
| Second Post | postviews_total | 2525 | 0555555 |

What can I do? I tried with this query to get my return, but I don't see how I can get a row added and my SQL query to understand that it's the same two values.

sql

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_title AS 'Listing Title',
wp_postmeta.meta_key AS 'Field', 
wp_postmeta.meta_value as 'Value', 
wp_640837_postmeta.meta_value as 'Phone' 
FROM wp_640837_posts 
JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'post_views_count'
```

Comment: I'm trying to fix my table problem in the post, sorry.

Comment: It looks to me like you're on a multisite WordPress installation with many many sites. If you use the `wp_640837_posts` table you shuld probably use the corresponding `wp_640837_postmeta` table, as it will contain the metadata for your posts.

Comment: @O.Jones No sorry, I have edited the code to remove the number generated by WordPress and I forgot two lines ;) - But now with the solution below, everything is Ok. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.
you need to join `wp_postmeta` table twice.

```sql
SELECT wp_posts.post_title AS 'Listing Title', postview.meta_key AS 'Field', postview.meta_value AS 'Value', tel.meta_value AS 'Phone'
FROM wp_640837_posts
    JOIN wp_postmeta AS postview ON wp_640837_posts.ID = postview.post_id AND postview.meta_key = 'postviews_total'
    JOIN wp_postmeta AS tel ON wp_640837_posts.ID = tel.post_id AND tel.meta_key = 'listing_tel'
```